Issue Changing iOS App Icon and Splash Screen in .NET MAUI Projec
I'm encountering a problem when updating the app icon and splash screen for the iOS target in my .NET MAUI project. I've followed these steps:
I removed the default files named appicon.svg, appiconfg.svg, and splash.svg from the project. Added custom icons and splash: I replaced the deleted files with my own icon images and a splash screen image (see attached screenshot).
enter image description here
I've made changes to the project file (.csproj) and Info.plist file. Please see the setting below:


<ItemGroup>
        <!-- App Icon -->
      <MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\dm.svg" ForegroundFile="Resources\AppIcon\dmfg.svg"        Color="#113946"/>
        <!-- Splash Screen -->
      <MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\splash.svg" Color="#113946"         BaseSize="400,600" />
        <!-- Images -->
        <MauiImage Include="Resources\Images\*" />
        <MauiImage Update="Resources\Images\dotnet_bot.png" Resize="True" BaseSize="300,185" />

        <!-- Custom Fonts -->
        <MauiFont Include="Resources\Fonts\*" />

        <!-- Raw Assets (also remove the "Resources\Raw" prefix) -->
        <MauiAsset Include="Resources\Raw\**" LogicalName="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
</ItemGroup>





<key>XSAppIconAssets</key>
<string>Assets.xcassets/dm.appiconset</string>



Despite these changes, the app icon and splash screen remain unchanged on the iOS device or simulator. In contrast, the Android target in the same project has updated correctly with my custom icons and splash screen.
Would be much appreciated for any insights and suggestions.

They wont change, until you use MAC to build it.

Let me go  a bit in details. It is the way hot reload works. It is very useful to debug something, as long as it is not resources. When you prepare signed release, all those resources get prepared to the archive, and are recognized in IOS. Everything will work fine, trust me. But until then, do not get surprised if you are missing the icon, splash, or the languages for localization. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/hot-restart?view=net-maui-8.0#limitations

Thanks for the info, it all makes sense now. So does it mean I will need a Mac to publish to the app store? LoL I thought I could get away from it.

Yes, you need MAC. But you can just connect to. You don't have to actually use it. Well, you need to install some prerequisites, some certificates, add some emulators (for taking screenshots mainly). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/pair-to-mac?view=net-maui-8.0
